# WPF datepicker disable dates from resources

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I want to create a resource for a DatePicker where the dates are available upto and including today. I have found something about BlackoutDates but I can't set it in resources. I tried the following.

```
    <Style x:Key="StandardDatetime" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
        <Setter Property="BlackoutDates">
            <Setter.Value>
                <CalendarDateRange Start="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

To be clear, I want the user not to be able to enter an invalid date at all ,not through the calendar and not through the textbox.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've not specified the date range correctly for the BlackoutDates.

The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates that you need to specify both the start and end properties.

So if you want all dates up to today you'll need:

```
<CalendarDateRange Start="{x:Static system:DateTime.MinValue}"
                   End="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today}"/>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work when i try to add this to the resources. I get an error about the BlackoutDates property not being a DependencyProperty or something.